# Google Analytics PHP API Redirect URI

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api

I'm testing the Google Analytics API (with oauth 2.0) on my local machine and I want to know if it's possible to get it to work this way as they request me to insert a Redirect URI in the Google APIs Console and then enter it in my code but I do not know what this Redirect URI should be?

My current Redirect URI is `https://localhost/oauth2callback` and I tried `https://gapi.local/oauth2callback` but neither works for me.

**I get this error message:**
`Fatal error: Call to undefined method apiClient::setClientRedirectUri() in C:\xampp\htdocs\webs\gapi\HelloAnalyticsApi.php on line 15`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: **When** does that error happen? Before redirecting? After you were redirected back? If the browser was redirected back, does it actually run any line of your code?

Comment: The problem is that no redirection occurs. When I run the file, it's supposed to display the amount of visitors to the site of my GA account but it just displays the error message above. I used the exact same code as in this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/tutorials/hello-analytics-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [google-api-php-client library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) has no method `setClientRedirectUri()` in `apiClient`. The correct method is called [`setRedirectUri()`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/tutorials/hello-analytics-api#authorize_access):

```
$client = new apiClient();
$client->setApplicationName('Hello Analytics API Sample');

// Visit //code.google.com/apis/console?api=analytics to generate your
// client id, client secret, and to register your redirect uri.
$client->setClientId('insert_your_oauth2_client_id');
$client->setClientSecret('insert_your_oauth2_client_secret');
$client->setRedirectUri('insert_your_oauth2_redirect_uri');
$client->setDeveloperKey('insert_your_developer_key');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'));
```

Comment: Thanks Jan. Embarrassing beginner mistake on my side.