# proxy for google Analytics traffic

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I am planing to use Google Analytics for my Hybrid mobile application. 
I have a special use case that, instead of google analytic call directly from browser. I want to route this call from my server. Which means there should be no call to google Analytics for a user device, everything will be though my servers. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: you can achieve this with the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide)

Comment: Thanks @CrayonViolent it was helpful. Is there any way we can write some code which just forward all the request which is coming from client to google analytics though our server (So that i don't have to manually copy the headers,params etc to my request)

Comment: Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29119361/google-analytics-proxy/29130925

Comment: This is how I do it and it works nicely: http://kennystechtalk.blogspot.com/2016/03/adblockanalytics.html