# How to implement Google analytics for intranet based application

Tags: web-applications, google-analytics, intranet, visitor-statistic

We have a website working in intranet. I have to implement google analytics solution to know the visitors behaviour. Could you please help me on this how can i implement it ?

Comment: If public servers are accessible from within the intranet you can just implement GA like in any other website. Else this post might offer a possible approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29119361/google-analytics-proxy/29130925#29130925