# Google Analytics Server Side - hide tracking id

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

analytics.js seems to post all the collected data to https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1 url. Is there any way to change the url and make it post (except the tracking Id) to an url located on my server?

I need this because I want to hide the tracking Id and manually send the collected data through Measurement Protocol server-side. Of course I could write my own JS to do that but that means I have to replicate all the functionality from analytics.js. Tried to find the source code of analytics.js and just tweak it accordingly to my needs but no luck so far.

Comment: Related (I think): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29119361/google-analytics-proxy/29130925#29130925

Comment: @EikePierstorff related maybe but not enough to be a duplicate.  Good find though.

Comment: @EikePierstorff I believe that's what I need but I have to try it myself and see if it works. It explains how to overwrite the end point and that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Why do you want to hide the tracking id?

Comment: Well some people think it's not secure to expose the tracking id. Since some online companies drive their marketing campaigns based on the stats gathered with GA, they might be right in some respects. I found out about the Measurement Protocol recently and quite surprised that all you need is a tracking id and you can start pushing data :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analytics.js is designed to write to the Google analytics collection endpoint it does not contain the ability to change that end point.

Your best bet will be to copy analytics js and change the end point yourself.  Removing the tracking id however will be a bigger change.

Comment: Yes, that's the best approach, except I can't find analytics js source code.

Comment: This is the only location https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js its probably been minified you will have to unminifie it to start with.

Comment: Well that's what I'm trying to avoid because it's quite hackish.

Comment: IMO what you are trying to do is kind of the definition of hackish what did you expect :o)

Comment: I know! But trying to find the best approach of the hack :)). I'm quite surprised it's not that common what I'm trying to do cause once you have someone's tracking id you could easily mess up his stats...